# PHP code isnt sending email

Tags: php, email

I have the following code below which is pulling a template and information to send an email from some PHP code that I did not write. However I need to try and get it working. I'm really basic when it comes to coding so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
$fh = fopen('templates/customer.eml','r');

        $emailContents = fread($fh, filesize('templates/customer.eml'));
        $emailContents = str_replace(":name:", $person->first . " " . $person->last, $emailContents);
        $emailContents = str_replace(":meeting_name:", $meeting->name, $emailContents);
        $emailContents = str_replace(":chair:", $chair->first . " " . $chair->last, $emailContents);

        fclose($fh);

        $header = "FROM: vra@vodafone.com\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .="Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
        mail($person->email , "Meeting Request", $emailContents, $header);

        echo $person->email;
```

Comment: How did you check the mail isn't being send instead of it not being delivered / coming in the spam folder?

Comment: try  if(!mail){   and is the person->email filled?

Comment: I'm currently using my gmail account to check if i receive the email but nothing is coming through, which nothing is nor in the spam folder. John, how can i check if the person-> email is being filled?

Comment: Is you SMTP configured correctly. Are you trying from localhost?